# Mosquitoes in Plitvice National Park

Tags: croatia, national-parks, outdoor-activities, insects

Are mosquitoes prevalent in Croatia's Plitvice National Park? At least in July. My guidebook has a few warnings about Zagreb but doesn't say anything about the park. Usually places with water and trees have plenty of mosquitoes.

Comment: Anecdotally, [here is a blog](http://hisandhertravel.co/post/54099487330/tips-for-visiting-the-plitvice-lakes-our-hike-with) that mentions they wished they had taken bug spray....

Comment: Diametrically anecdotal :) [here is a WP article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/travel/game-of-croatia-for-this-family-of-six/2014/07/31/29b54516-168d-11e4-85b6-c1451e622637_story.html) that mentions they had absolutely no bugs/mosquitoes...

Comment: @CGCampbell they went in early june, might have been cold. 

It's likely there will be mosquitoes, but even then, carrying bug spray on holiday is obvious, and there's not much more than that you can do about it...

Comment: Yes, we will be carrying bug spray but when there are bugs, I usually adjust my clothes to be more covered because that is more efficient than repellent in my experience which of course has to be balanced with how hot it will be. For forecast if for rather high temperatures when we get there next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were there (late) July - (early) August 2014 and didn't have any problems.  As previous contributors have said, always carry bug spray anyway (Lidl do one that's pretty good) and take plenty of water to drink.

Comment: No mosquitoes today or yesterday. Lots of other harmless bugs but nothing that bites yet and they usually find me easily!